# How to replace href value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which changes the big image according to the thumbnail clicked (this part is working).

I want to change accordingly the url in the href (so that each big image shown has a link to another URL). <-- this last part is not working.

----------HERE IS THE CODE ----------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="language" content="english"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">

<title>image swapping </title>



<script type="text/javascript">

function init(){

   th=document.getElementById('thumbs').getElementsByTagName('img');
for(c=0;c<th.length;c++) {
th[c].onclick=function() {
   swapImage(this.src);
   swapFile(this.href);

   }
  }
 }

function swapImage(url){

   str=url.lastIndexOf(".");
   str1=url.substring(str-1);
   str2=url.substring(str);

   url=url.replace(str1,str2);

   document.getElementById('bigpic').src=url;

 }

 function swapFile(url){

   str=url.lastIndexOf(".");
   str1=url.substring(str-1);
   str2=url.substring(str);

   url=url.replace(str1,str2);

   document.getElementById('file').href=url;

 }

   window.addEventListener?
   window.addEventListener('load',init,false):
   window.attachEvent('onload',init);

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
 <a href="01.html" id="file"><img id="bigpic" src="images/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div id="thumbs">
 <img src="images/01t.jpg" alt="01t.jpg">
 <img src="images/02t.jpg" alt="02t.jpg">
 <img src="images/03t.jpg" alt="03t.gif">
 <img src="images/04t.jpg" alt="04t.png">
 <img src="images/05t.jpg" alt="05t.png">
 <img src="images/06t.jpg" alt="06t.png">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

This question might get flagged as a duplicate, but here's the answer anyway.

To change the href value of an anchor:

```
document.getElementById('file').setAttribute('href',url);
```

Comment: Why use `setAttribute()` rather than just: `document.getElementById('file').href = url;`?

Comment: Certain attributes of a DOM element are altered more reliably by using setAttribute. I looked into the root cause a few years ago, and can't remember the underlying reason. It's now almost muscle memory that I set the "id", "src" and "href" via setAttribute. Try it on IE. Maybe it only works this way.

Comment: There is no reason I'm aware of to use `setAttribute()` for `.id` or `.href` or `.src`.

Comment: Now you know. It's more likely that you figure this out when you dynamically create DOM elements by using document.createElement. You'll be puzzled why attributes such as "id" are not set correctly without the help of setAttribute. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I'm still aware of no reasons - you haven't described any specific example that supports your claim.  I've been using the direct property access for the last 5 years and never had an issue.  I'm open to a demonstration, but haven't seen one yet.

Comment: Tried both options below and it does not replace...

    `document.getElementById('file').setAttribute('href',url);`

    `document.getElementById('file').href = url;`

Comment: Only the image swaps (01.jpg, 02.jpg, 03.jpg, etc.) The href stays at "01.html" it does not swap to "02.html", "03.html", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change logic slightly...Thumbnails doesn't have links, right?

```
    <script>
function init(){

   th=document.getElementById('thumbs').getElementsByTagName('img');
for(c=0;c<th.length;c++) {
th[c].onclick=function() {
   swapImage(this.src);
   swapFile(this.getAttribute("alt"));

   }
  }
 }

function swapImage(url){

   str=url.lastIndexOf(".");
   str1=url.substring(str-1);
   str2=url.substring(str);

   url=url.replace(str1,str2);

   document.getElementById('bigpic').src=url;

 }

 function swapFile(hurl){

   str=hurl.lastIndexOf(".");
   str1=hurl.substring(str-1);
   str2=hurl.substring(str);

   hurl=hurl.replace(str1,str2);
hurl=hurl.replace('.jpg','.html'); // for html extension at the end of the link

   document.getElementById('file').href=hurl;

 }

   window.addEventListener?
   window.addEventListener('load',init,false):
   window.attachEvent('onload',init);

</script>
```

Html:

```
 <div>
 <a href="01.html" id="file"><img id="bigpic" src="images/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div id="thumbs">
 <img src="images/01t.jpg" alt="01t.jpg">
 <img src="images/02t.jpg" alt="02t.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Great. And, if you want .html extension in link, one small addition: hurl=hurl.replace('.jpg','.html'); in swapfile function...

Comment: Thanks. I was just writing that question! You answered it before I posted it. It works! Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code in Firebug, and found the error:

```
   th=document.getElementById('thumbs').getElementsByTagName('img');
for(c=0;c<th.length;c++) {
th[c].onclick=function() {
   swapImage(this.src);
   swapFile(this.href);

   }
  }
 }
```

"this" refers to th[c], and now look at your image tags:

```
 <img src="images/01t.jpg" alt="01t.jpg">
 <img src="images/02t.jpg" alt="02t.jpg">
 <img src="images/03t.jpg" alt="03t.gif">
```

They don't have href attribute, so your swapFile function fails and terminates script execution. You could add custom attributes to these images:

```
 <img href="link1" src="images/01t.jpg" alt="01t.jpg">
 <img href="link2" src="images/02t.jpg" alt="02t.jpg">
 <img href="link3" src="images/03t.jpg" alt="03t.gif">
```

But images are not anchors, so th[c].href will not give you the value.

Here's the new init function:

```
function init(){

   th=document.getElementById('thumbs').getElementsByTagName('img');

for(c=0;c<th.length;c++) {
th[c].onclick=function() {
   swapImage(this.src);
   swapFile(this.attributes.href.value); // <-- fixed this line

   }
  }
}
```

I have tested the code locally and it runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function red(){
var a = document.getElementById("your_tag_name");
a.href = 'www.thelinkyouwanttoadd.com';
}
</script
 </head>
<body>
 <a id="your_tag_name" href="www.google.com" onclick="red()">
</body>
</html>
```